# Implementation of an advanced code editor using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

How to implement a code editor with features like syntax highlighting,code completion,code snippets to an extent like in Visual studio.
Iam using visual studio 2010 to create the editor.I found a syntax rich text box which does the syntax highlighting but i want to add much more features to the code editor.
plz suggest.

Comment: You've already listed enough features that will take some time implemeting from scratch. Do you need more feature suggestion? Or you have some other quiestion?

Comment: No Code completion is mainly what im looking for if you could help me in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio shell is your choice. Below links might be of your interest:

- [Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Integrated)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=115)
- [Visual Studio Isolated Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685691.aspx)
- [Integrated Shell and Isolated Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685612.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this [MSDN Walkthrough on Displaying Statement Completion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx)

From above Link:

> Statement completion is typically triggered by typing certain characters, for example, by typing the beginning of an identifier such as "using". It is typically dismissed by pressing the SPACEBAR, TAB, or ENTER to commit a selection. IntelliSense features that are triggered by typing a character can be implemented by using a command handler for the keystrokes (the IOleCommandTarget interface) and a handler provider that implements the IVsTextViewCreationListener interface. To create the completion source, which is the list of identifiers that participate in completion, implement the ICompletionSource interface and a completion source provider (the ICompletionSourceProvider interface).